# Drilling a hole to let the shin-daleds out

Tags: halacha, home-house

I've been told recently that there is a halacha to drill a hole where you seal up a gap in an outside wall to let the shin-daleds out or something.  I'm pretty skeptical about that, as is my rav, but he asked about it and was told it is a real thing.  However, he says he isn't sure of the exact scope of this "halacha" (quotes are his!) and isn't sure if I need to worry about somewhere where a window was, or somewhere which now has a brick missing from what was an external wall but the gap was only there once a new room has been built on the other side.

Does anyone have a reliable source for the details of this "halacha"?

Comment: We were told this when sealing up an old fireplace / chimney - that you have to drill a hole through the board to let out the *shedim*. Not sure what the *mekor* is. Anyway in your scenario you could just use a ventilation brick.

Comment: @pcoz That is now an internal wall though so not sure that would even help!  We're also removing chimney breasts completely on the downstairs floor and doing quite a few other things so really confused what the scope of this is and how to deal with some of it!